# How to properly zoom a WebView together with it's background image?

Tags: android, webview, zooming, imageview

I'm using the following code which only zooms the loadData. How is it possible to zoom the image inside? Thank you in advance!

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myid);    
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image.jpg");
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
web.setBackgroundColor(0);
web.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
web.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally did it by insersting the image.jpg in an html file which took the place of loadUrl().